# Stack using linked list in C, freeing temp_node in pop function but still want to return it

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, stack

I am implementing a stack using linked list in C, and I stumbled upon two issues:

1. I need the `stack_pop` function to return a valid value `temp`, that is the temporary node/cell, and therefore, I can't free it. So, 1) Do you think freeing each node for every pop function call is better than until the end using the `stack_destroy()` 2) How can I achieve both, `free(temp)` and return it at the same time in `stack_pop`?
2. How bad my implementation becomes not using `exit(1)` in both `stack_push` and `stack_pop` functions?

This is the implementation:

```
//// Stack

// Linked list
typedef struct {
    int data;
    Cell* next;
} Cell;

struct stack_l {
    size_t count;
    Cell *top;
};
typedef struct stack_l *Stack;
```

Comment: You may implement two separate functions: `const Cell *stack_peek(Stack stack)` to access / read the contents of the top item, and `void stack_pop(Stack stack)` to remove the top item from the stack.

Comment: Ok, I just want the interface of: structure stack, push, pop, and check if empy. I don't accomplish that in a nice way?

Comment: The interface you describe is useful and sufficient as long as your stack keeps simple values, like a single `int`. However if you need to keep some bigger data (for example a 3D point with a text label), it may be easier to access it with a pointer than copy to a temp variable and then copy the temp again in the `return` statement.

Comment: How would you fix that in my implementation?

Comment: stack_pop or stack_removetop: `Cell*top=stack->top; if (top) {stack->top=top->next; free(top);}`

Comment: stack_peek: `return stack->top;`

Comment: Problem in your `stack_create()` routine: you declare a variable pointing to a `struct stack_l` but you do not assign it any meaningful value and actually you never create the  `struct stack_l`.

Comment: You mean I should have done it like this: `Stack stackL = malloc(sizeof(Stack));` ?

Comment: Precisely :) Consequently you should also release the stack after use: `free(stack);` at the end of `stack_destroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got `stack_pop` declared to return an `int`, but you're attempting to return a `Cell *` which doesn't make sense.

Copy the value in the popped cell to a local variable, free the popped cell, then return the value.

```
    temp = stack->top;
    stack->top = stack->top->next;
    temp->next = NULL;
    stack->count--;
    int val = temp.data;
    free(temp)
    return val;
```

Also, it makes no sense to call `exit` in either `stack_push` or `stack_pop` as that ends the program.

Comment: also `==` should be `=`

Comment: Thanks, do you think the implementation is short and correct?

Comment: @pzii22 is too complicated. See my answer - especially the second part

Comment: Ok, what is the point of complicatedness? I just followed standard book implementations. I also made it clearer, by having the node and stack structures separate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bit overcomplicated. You only need to remember the previous stack pointer. Nothing else

```
typedef struct stack
{
    int data;
    struct stack *prev;
}stack;


stack *push(stack **sp, int data)
{
    stack *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    if(new)
    {
        new -> prev = *sp;
        new -> data = data;
        *sp = new;
    }
    return new;
}

int isempty(stack *sp)
{
     return !stack_pointer;
}

int pop(stack **sp)
{
    stack *new;
    int result = 0;
    if(sp && *sp)
    {
        result = (*sp) -> data;
        new = (*sp) -> prev;
        free(*sp);
        *sp = new;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    stack *stack_pointer = NULL;
    int result;

    push(&stack_pointer, 1);
    push(&stack_pointer, 2);
    push(&stack_pointer, 3);

    do
    {
        result = pop(&stack_pointer);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }while(stack_pointer)   ;
    printf("Stack was empty so the loop has exited\n");
}
```

Comment: But I need to do it with next, not prev. I will use prev when doing double linked list.

Comment: @pzii22 I think you do not understand what the stack is. You can only push on top, or pop from the top. You only need to know the current position on the stack and reference to the previous. Nothing else as stack by definition cannot be traversed. It is FIFO queue.,

Comment: Yes, that s the stack, and that s what I am doing with my implementation, no?

Comment: You try to do it very strange way. See how simpleand logical  is my implementation comparing to yours

Comment: Ok, but I need an interface that looks like this: structure stack, push, pop, and check if empy. I don't accomplish that in a nice way?

Comment: @pzii22 no, you don't. You cant even store all possible `int` values using that implementation. I deleted the first part to do not confuse you.